# Android Wifi scan: Differentiating a "real" access point from a mobile hotspot of a mobile phone?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

When I make a scan using the WifiManager from Android SDK, I can get all scannable access points near me. However, I noticed that the result include all access points, including those mobile phones that have mobile hotspot turned on.

What would be the efficient way to differentiate/filter them, so that I can just only record the "real" access points and not everything?

Thanks.

edit - 3/3/2015
While searching for answer myself, I found the following post:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/is-there-any-way-to-differentiate-mac-address-of-an-access-point-from-that-of-a

I guess if there is no direct/simple way, I would need to build a database of manufacturer based on OUI then filter the scan results I have. With this at least I can tell devices that states Samsung or Xperia are not fixed access points. Perhaps that's the only solution for the time being.

Comment: In what way is a smart phone _not_ a real hotspot?

Comment: There should not be any technical difference at all. It's like you're asking: When browsing the web, how can I distinguish websites that run on "real" servers from those who just run on a server PC in someone's home"

Comment: I think I need to make it clearer: I wish to scan for available access points, but I am not interested in those mobile phone ones. I am only searching for "real" access points, as in those fixed ones. Hope this clears up my question.

Comment: Did you find a solution?